# Despite completing the task in Workflow (Approving the Document) , Workflow column in doucument library showing Work In Progress?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, approval

[image]

As shown in the image , One of our clients approved given document the workflow Internal Approval Showing **approved** but the approval status shown in "**In Progress**".

Also the user is getting repetitive reminder mails to approve the document even though he has already approved the Docs .

Kindly help me in this issue .

Comment: did you check the number of approval levels?

Comment: Yes workflow is assigned to a single person only .